# How to expand the dataframe based on the column values?

Tags: python-3.x, pandas, dataframe

I have this dataframe:

[image]

```
utc  arc_time_s tec_tecu    elevation_deg   lat_e_deg   lon_e_deg
01.01.2018 01:19    54  3.856   17.35   57.44   25.02
01.01.2018 01:19    53  4.021   17.29   57.47   25.03
01.01.2018 01:19    52  4.029   17.22   57.51   25.05
01.01.2018 01:19    51  4.015   17.15   57.54   25.07
01.01.2018 01:19    50  3.997   17.08   57.57   25.09
```

What I want is expanding the dataframe based on lat_e_deg column to have all values with decimal scale 2.

I found the method resample but it seems like only can be used for datetime column.

So as an output I want to have like this:

[image]

How can I do this?

Comment: Is the input dataframe the same as the output?

Comment: No, it was mistake. I have already corrected it!

Comment: You can show data as images if it helps, but you **must** share it in text format for others to copy it and reproduce. If you do not, most will simply pass their way and will not try to answer, and some will downvote.

Comment: Oh thank you for your advise, I have included also in text form the dataframe

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
import pandas as pd
import numpy as np

# reconstruct part of your DataFrame for testing purposes:
df = pd.DataFrame([[17.35, 57.44], [17.29, 57.47], [17.22, 57.51]], 
                 columns = ['elevation_deg', 'lat_e_deg'])

# create a Series of the desired stepwise values:
lat_e_deg_expanded = pd.Series(np.arange(start = min(df['lat_e_deg']), 
                                         stop = max(df['lat_e_deg']), 
                                         step = 0.01), 
                               name = 'lat_e_deg')

# merge the expanded series with the original DataFrame and sort:
df_expanded = pd.merge(df, lat_e_deg_expanded, 
                       on = 'lat_e_deg', 
                       how = 'outer')
df_expanded.sort_values(by = 'lat_e_deg', inplace = True)
```

Answer (score 1):

You can create `pd.Series` with `step = 0.01` and then join to original dataframe.

Example code assuming `df` is dataframe with missing decimal values:

```
ts = pd.Series(np.arange(start = 57.44, stop = 57.57, step=0.01), name = "t")
df = pd.DataFrame({'t': [57.44, 57.47, 57.57]})

df2 = pd.merge(ts, df, how = "left").sort_values("t")
```

Result:

```
        t
0   57.44
1   57.45
2   57.46
3   57.47
4   57.48
5   57.49
6   57.50
7   57.51
8   57.52
9   57.53
10  57.54
11  57.55
12  57.56
13  57.57
```